# Looping through cursor with additional select vs Fetch Into

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My Current approach is something like

```
var_row_output tablename%rowtype;

cursor main_cur IS
   SELECT id 
   FROM tablename;

BEGIN
FOR rec in main_cur LOOP
   SELECT * 
   INTO var_row_output
   FROM tablename
   WHERE id= rec.id;

-- do stuff
End Loop;
END;
```

Would it be better to go with something like

```
var_row_output tablename%rowtype;

cursor main_cur IS
   SELECT * 
   FROM tablename;

BEGIN
LOOP
   FETCH main_cur into var_row_output;
   EXIT WHEN main_cur%NOTFOUND;
   --do stuff
END LOOP;
END;
```

We in general take the first approach every time at my workplace for working with cursors.  I'm just curious if there is a performance hit to doing that?  Which way is preferable?

Answer (score 2):

You are executing an extra `select` in each iteration of the loop in your first example, so that would likely be somewhat of a performance hit. Also, the code is more succinct in the second example. But I also prefer `for` loops, with implicit cursors, like this:

```
begin
  for myrow in (select * from tablename) loop
    null; -- do stuff with myrow
  end loop;
end;
```